# 3 column association table? Modeling users betting on other users through matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I want to implement a betting system for my app, where a user can bet on a player to win a match vs. another player.

Here is an example scenario:

> Match 1 contains User 2 vs. User 3.
>
> User 1 wants to "bet" on User 2 to win.

So in order to uniquely identify a **bet** we have to have 3 pieces of information.

> 1) The better's id (User 1)
>
> 2) The match id (Match 1)
>
> 3) The player who is being bet on (User 2)

So as a novice rails developer I've only developed association tables with only 2 columns. My question is how exactly do you model an association table "Bets" that contains 3 columns?

I want to be able to say

> user.current_bets

to bring up all current bets that a user has placed, which will say what match I've bet on and what user I placed the bet on.

Also, in any given match, I want to be able to see all of the users that have bet on player 1

> match.p1_user_bet_list

And all of the users who have bet on player 2

> match.p2_user_bet_list

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to see all of the users that have bet on player 1 `def p1_user_bet_list(player_id) where(player_id: player_id) end`

Comment: Sorry NitinJ, not sure how that helps. The association between a User and a match and the bet placed on another user is not formulated anywhere in your code.

Comment: Ohh I assume that you already defined association . Please see rails guide for association .

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bets, foreign_key: 'better_id'
  has_many :bet_ons, foreign_key: 'favorite_id'
  has_many :favorites, through: :bets
  has_many :betters, through: :bet_ons
end

class Bets < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :match
  belongs_to :better, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :favorite, class_name: 'User'
end
```

To bring up all bets a user has placed, you'd use:

```
user.bets
```

To get all the users who have bet on player 1, you'd use:

```
player1.betters
```

Note that I have not tested this.

More information on associations here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: JKen13579, I tried out your solution and thought that it would work, but unfortunately the problem actually isn't solved. For example, player1.betters returns the list of users that have bet on you, the problem is that we don't know what match they bet on you for. So User 2 could have bet on you for match A and also in another match X but we have no way of identifying that, since player1.betters just returns a list of Users NOT coupled with the match.

Comment: Could you use `@bets_on = user.bet_ons`? This will give you the list of bets that have been placed on the `user`, and you if you iterate through the `@bets_on` with `@bets_on.each do |b|`, you can get the match and the user who made the bet with `b.match` and `b.better`, respectively.